Memory issue in linux vm
I have a linux vm, where the memory usage is very high..
[]$ free -mt
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15885       13606        1998           2         279        1687
Swap:             0           0           0
Total:        15885       13606        1998

Total Memory: 15,885 MB.
Used Memory: 13606 MB.
Free Memory: 1998 MB.
[]$ ps -eo rss | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}'
4119.69

Sum of all the process resident memory is 4119.69MB
[]$ sudo slabtop -o
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 796742 / 840221 (94.8%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 14634 / 14634 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 80 / 107 (74.8%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 88251.60K / 97230.54K (90.8%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.12K / 8.00K
...
....

Kernel Slab Memory Usage:
Total Slab Memory: ~972 MB.
Active Slab Memory: ~882 MB.
[]$ mount | grep -i tmpfs | awk {'print $3}' | sudo xargs du -sh
0   /dev
2.6M    /run
0   /sys/fs/cgroup
4.0K    /tmp 

Tmpfs memory usage is very less < 2.7MB
[]$ column -t /proc/modules | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024/1024}'
4.93896 

The kernel modules sizes sum is 4.93MB.
So from these data (all sizes in MB) 4119.69 (user space process rss) + 972 (kernel slab memory usage) + 2.7 (tmpfs memory) + 4.9 (kernel modules loaded size) =  ~5100MB .. All memory usage account for ~5100MB of memory not sure where the rest 13606(free memory) - 5100(total accounted memory) = ~8506 MB(un accounted) is being used.
What is consuming ~8506 MB of memory in my linux vm?

Do you have ZFS? // Your questions has lots of small mistakes with the numbers.

All the filesystem are formatted with ext4

Can you add "cat /proc/meminfo " output? Also, which hypervisor are you running on?
